# CSS place text on top of image

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.content {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.content_div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  font-size: 16px
}

.title {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.title_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; float:left;">
  <div class="title_div">
    <p class="title">801 BAOER BLACK ROLLER PEN</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://52.66.90.164/Show_barcode">
  <div class="content_div">
    <p class="content">52305</p>
    <p class="content">Packet</p>
    <p class="content">MRP: 300</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the same layout but the title and content width is 100% of the image. If I remove title then the content width is according to the image. Title width is not according to the image. How can I make title width according to the image? If I add an absolute position in title parent `div` then the layout is changed. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Say NO to inline!

Comment: I tried messing around with this but the inline styles are just getting too confusing. Apply styles through CSS and give it meaningful class names.

Comment: shah rushabh: Learn how to use CSS in a separate file.

Comment: @shahrushabh see: https://www.w3schools.com

Comment: Say NO to w3schools, great now you made me type it and I have to go wash my hands :/ - Use proper resources such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS or https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-css or https://www.pluralsight.com/paths/css

Comment: @Nope lol haha It's a great place to learn things like css though..

Comment: @JoniVR Basically, while w3... has improved over the years, it is still a source I avoid as it contains often outdated or sometimes even plain wrong information. As it says here, https://www.w3fools.com/ ,  the issues are mostly resolved these days but I would always prefer MDN documentation or paid online course over that.

Comment: Please check it I changed code.

Comment: @shahrushabh for the content_div, you could just get the <p> values by using `.content_div p` in your css, saves you from adding the `content` class everywhere

Comment: @JoniVR I made this for temporary at production this will change please focus on the problem instead of quality.

Comment: @Nope You're right, it's most easily accessible though (and free). I'll keep that in mind next time I recommend it.

Comment: @shahrushabh If you don't want to change the size of the image or change the font-size of the text you can at best center them. Move the `img` tag into the div below the `p` tag. Remove the `float:left` on the `p` tag and add `text-align:center;` to the `div` the `p` and now also the `img` tag are in.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `width: 100%;` to the image would solve this, but as VXp said, inline styles are rarely a good idea!

Comment: Barcode width and height are user-defined. Then this value will change Height and Width of Image. Alternative way? The image must be the same size.

Comment: Not easily - the trouble is the width of the container is being set by the widest element within it, which in this case is your title.

Comment: If you don't want to change the size of the image or change the font-size of the text you can at best center them. Move the `img` tag into the div below the `p` tag. Remove the `float:left` on the `p` tag and add `text-align:center;` to the `div` the `p` and now also the `img` tag are in.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a fixed width to your div (.container) (I separated css from html). I set the container to the same with as your image (285px). If you don't do that, the container does not know where to take the width from and will expand if the content is too large.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 285px;
}

.product {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 20px
}

.product > p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.below-barcode {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  font-size: 16px
}

.below-barcode > p {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="product">
      <p>801 BAOER BLACK ROLLER PEN</p>
   </div>
   <img src="http://52.66.90.164/Show_barcode"> 
   <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; left:0; top:100%;font-size:16px">
      <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:2px;overflow-wrap: break-word;">52305</p>
      <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:2px;overflow-wrap: break-word;">Packet</p>
      <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:2px;overflow-wrap: break-word;">MRP: 300</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helped